# Good JSON but browser throws error

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a PHP script that is building the header portion of an HTML(5) document.  Part of what is being emitted is something like this

```
$rtn = <<<RTN
<script type='text/javascript'>
var _scrolls = {"alpha":{"cursorborder":"1px dashed rgba(200,13,57,1)"}};
var _floors = new Array(10000,{$mqt},{$mqf});
</script>
RTN;
```

The JSON is valid - at least, JSONlint.com seems to think so.  However, in my browser (Chrome on Windows) this throws up an error Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token illegal.

By dint of some experiment I have narrowed down the problem to the last attribute

```
"cursorborder":"1px dashed rgba(200,13,57,1)"
```

For some reason the browser is taking exception to the spaces in the attribute value.  If I collapse that string so that it reads

```
"cursorborder":"1pxdashedrgba(200,13,57,1)"
```

the syntax error message disappears.  I cannot think of any rational explanation for this.  For completeness I guess I should mention that the JSON is being generated server side courtesy of json_encode.

Perhaps someone out here can tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Wild guess: did you reduce the string to one line when narrowing it down? You have line breaks inside the string which is not allowed in JavaScript. [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/6Mdhd/)--you'll notice that the version with no line breaks doesn't throw the error.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you would want to pass JSON to the variable instead of an actual object. Line breaks would be ok in an object definition.

Comment: you are showing us the code that generated the HTML - show us the actual HTML - it's possible there's an assumption you've made about the output which is not valid.

Comment: you're not saving your var as a json object but as a string because of the first and last quote

Comment: @aversag Sorry, but there is no such thing as "JSON object". JSON is always text (string). If you remove the quotes, it becomes a JavaScript object.

Comment: yes you're right, an object, with json representation. try removing your first and last quote, you can also remove the double quotes for the keys

Comment: @DroidOS the same comment to you: that is not JSON, it's a JavaScript object. You can't use a JSON validator for something that isn't JSON. It doesn't throw an error for me: http://jsfiddle.net/KPPm4/ On the other hand the next line *might*, so please show the generated JavaScript instead of the PHP code.

Comment: So what're `$mqt` and `$mqf`?

Answer (score 3):

it doesn't throw an error if I remove the first and the last ' , like this:

```
var _scrolls = {"alpha": {"bouncescroll":true,"boxzoom":false,"enabletranslate3d":true,"dblclickzoom":true,"gesturezoom":true,"hwacceleration":true,"horizrailenabled":true,"enablekeyboard":true,"railalign":"right","enablemousewheel":true,"nativeparentscrolling":true,"enablescrollonselection":true,"sensitiverail":true,"smoothscroll":true,"spacebarenabled":true,"railvalign":"bottom","touchbehavior":false,"autohidemode":false,"cursorcolor":"rgba(245,146,30,1)","background":"rgba(127,255,142,1)","cursorborder":"1px dashed rgba(200,13,57,1)"}};
```

Comment: Thank you for the various comments.  The starting and ending quotes ' arose from a copy/paste when I posted this question.  The line breaks I put in to make the code readable - in hindsight an error since that put everyone on the wrong track.  I have edited the code sample in my question. The code is now the mare minimum that reproduces the scenario I have found.  I have JSON, not a Javascript literal and it does not have line breaks anyway (which should not matter for JSON). And yet the error persists - it goes away if I take out the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have literal line breaks in a JavaScript string literal.

Remove or escape them. Better: don't use JSON for this and just have a JavaScript object literal, that will save you from having to have a separate parse step.

Comment: yes, you can. you just need to escape those too with \ (just before the line-breaks).

Comment: @pozs — If you escape them, they aren't literals.

Comment: No. Literals can contain escape sequences.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals
http://jsfiddle.net/4Fv4U/

Comment: @pozs — It will be in a string literal. It won't be a literal new line. It will be an escaped new line.

Answer (score 1):

As Jonas said, remove the `'` from the beginning and the end of the string.

That way, the variable will become a valid Javascript Object and not just a long string containing JSON.